# Makefile path substitution with multiple wildcards

Tags: makefile

I have a target that is a path to a test.mk file which needs to be generated (modified by a script based on the configuration) and I want to extract a part of the path that is the component to be tested.

The path is in the following format, where [component] and [test_name] are unknown.

```
TEST=absolute_path/[component]/unit_tests/[test_name]/test.mk
```

I want to reformat this path as relative_path/[component] and I have tried this line which doesn't substitute anything.

```
$(TEST):
    @echo $(patsubst absolute_path/%/unit_tests/%, relative_path/%, $@)
```

The GNU make manual has this to say about patsubst so I think it should work with multiple wildcards in a single patsubst invocation:

> Here pattern may contain a ‘%’ which acts as a wildcard, matching any number of any characters within a word. If replacement also contains a ‘%’, the ‘%’ is replaced by the text that matched the ‘%’ in pattern. Only the first ‘%’ in the pattern and replacement is treated this way; any subsequent ‘%’ is unchanged.

Comment: Do you mean that `absolute_path` is fixed and must be hardcoded in the makefile?

Comment: "I think it should work with multiple wildcards in a single patsubst invocation". You appear to have overlooked the last sentence of the `patsubst` docuementation
you have quoted. Your problem is also unclear. You need to post an example makefile indicating
the gap(s) you don't know how to complete.

Comment: absolute_path and relative_path are known through variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you know the relative path. I also assume that the name of the component and the name of the test are variable (they can change). So I call them 'component_X' and 'test_name_Y'. Assuming all that, the following should work:

```
    # Definitions for the space-string and the newline-string
    # ---------------------------------------------------------
    nullstring :=
    space := $(nullstring) #End

    TEST=some/abs/path/component_X/unit_tests/test_name_Y/test.mk

    # Some manipulations of the path:
    # ---------------------------------
    TEMP1=$(subst /,$(space),$(TEST))
    TEMP2=$(filter-out $(lastword $(TEMP1)),$(TEMP1))
    TEMP3=$(filter-out $(lastword $(TEMP2)),$(TEMP2))
    TEMP4=$(filter-out $(lastword $(TEMP3)),$(TEMP3))
    ABS_PATH=$(subst $(space),/,$(filter-out $(lastword $(TEMP4)),$(TEMP4)))
    REL_PATH=some/rel/path
    REL_FILE_PATH=$(patsubst $(ABS_PATH)/%,$(REL_PATH)/%,$(TEST))
    COMP_NAME=$(firstword $(subst /,$(space),$(patsubst $(ABS_PATH)/%,$(nullstring)%,$(TEST))))
    TEST_NAME=$(firstword $(subst /,$(space),$(patsubst $(ABS_PATH)/$(COMP_NAME)/unit_tests/%,$(nullstring)%,$(TEST))))


    # The test target
    # ----------------
    $(TEST): FORCE
        @echo.
        @echo The calculated ABS_PATH:
        @echo $(ABS_PATH)
        @echo.
        @echo The chosen REL_PATH:
        @echo $(REL_PATH)
        @echo.
        @echo The relative file path:
        @echo $(REL_FILE_PATH)
        @echo.
        @echo The component name:
        @echo $(COMP_NAME)
        @echo.
        @echo The test name:
        @echo $(TEST_NAME)

    FORCE:
```

Don't forget that copy-pasting can lead to errors in make. You should replace all  4-spaces by a tab-character in the recipe lines.

Please let me know if this solution worked for you.
I tested it on Windows. But it should work on Linux as well.

**EDIT :**

I made a small error in the definition for `ABS_PATH=...`. Now it should be correct :-)

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick:
`@echo relative_path/$(firstword $(subst /, $(space), $(patsubst absolute_path/%, %, $@)))`

Comment: Or even better: `@echo relative_path/$(firstword $(subst /unit_tests/, , $(patsubst absolute_path/%, %, $@)))` as this will work even if the component is in a sub directory, which we aparently have.
`absolute_path/[component]/[subcomponent]/unit_tests/[test_name]/test.mk` => `relative_path/[component]/[subcomponent]`